# Automatically chopping lumps off polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, geoprocessing, modelbuilder, fme-form

I have a load of polygons that were originally digitised from CAD. These unfortunately include traingles that were used to sybolise the direction the polygon is facing. As can be seen here: [image]

The trangles are of uniform shape and size and are too numerous to remove manually, so I am trying to automate a sytem that finds them (based of angle and size?) and clips them off the polygons leaving the unsymbolised polygons. I was planing on either doing this using model builder and FME, but I'm no sure which tools/transformations to use. Has anyone got any experience of doing this, and if so how did they go about it and what tools did they use?

Thanks

Comment: If they were digitised from CAD it's possible that the data is saved as multi-part polygons, which could then be 'exploded' and allow you to remove the triangles.

Comment: Your're right a can't believe I didn't try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested above the solution to this is to edit the polygons and then using the explode [multi-part polygon tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m800000002000000) separate the triangles from the rest of the feature, select and delete.

[image]